# UiPath - Issue embedding double quotes around String

Tags: uipath

I have come across a peculiar problem while running a workflow on a different laptop. The workflow was running without issues on the original laptop that was used to design the workflow.
The issue seems to be simple and is with a “type into” activity which types into the bing webpage search box.
I need to embed a string within double quotes. This was working as expected on the original laptop but when I tried to run this in a new laptop, there seems to be some special characters appearing instead of double quotes.

Below is the string that should be typed into the search box.

“site:” + URL.ToString.Substring(4)+" “+”"“AS400"”"

A correct sample string typed in should look like the below.

site:bfa.ao “AS400”

But instead, it is getting typed as shown in the image below.

[image]

As can be seen, the first “A” character in the string gets typed into as Ä and the double quote is missing.

Please help why this is happening so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use:

`Chr(34)` as **double quote** char symbol.

So in you case it would be:

```
"site:" + URL.ToString.Substring(4) + " " + Chr(34) + "AS400" + Chr(34)
```